# Prevent Chrome from providing suggest pages on work computer

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome on both my personal and work computer.  I have a Google account which I have used to sign in to Chrome on my personal computer, but not on my work computer.  I have deliberately not signed in to Chrome on my work computer to help keep personal content from appearing on my work computer.  Despite this, Chrome on my work computer shows recently visited pages from my personal computer (when I open a new tab). These are pages that I have not visited on my work computer, and are *exceedingly* inappropriate for my work computer.

**How do I prevent Google Chrome from displaying these pages when I open a new tab on my work computer?**

I have tried clearing my browser history, and "removing" the people using Chrome, however, as soon as I log in to any website (like this one) Chrome recognizes its me, and shows the content again.

As an aside, as long as I never navigate to these pages on my work computer, this content will never be visible to my employer, right? (unless of course they are standing at my workstation when I open a new tab)

Comment: Have you ever signed into gmail or google drive on your work PC? If you go to Google, what does the top right hand corner look like?

Comment: I sign in to StackExchange with my Google account.  When I go to Google it shows my name and account in the top right

Comment: That would be the reason why. Although you are not signed into your Chrome profile which can sync your favorites and all that jazz, being singed in does sync your Google searches. Try signing out and that should stop the crazy search sync issues. I had the same problem myself. I could never figure out why my work searches kept showing up on my phone. Once I signed out, it stopped.

Comment: That seems to have done it, want to write that up in an answer?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. Was it the StackExchange that cause you to be signed in, or did you previously sign into Gmail or something? Just wondering so I can verify for the answer.

Comment: I only ever signed into StackExchange, but I do that with my Google Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are not signed into your *Chrome profile* which can sync your favorites and all that jazz, being singed into a single service linked through Google (Gmail, Google Drive, StackExchange, etc.) does sync your Google searches. In order to stop this, go to the Google homepage and sign out of your account.